# Undefined sanitization unable to detect a simple stack out-of-bound error

Tags: c++, indexoutofboundsexception, sanitization

```
#include <iostream>
void fill(int *);

int main() {
    int a[1];
    int b[1];
    a[0] = 1;
    b[0] = 2;
    fill(a);

    std::cout << *a << " " << *b << std::endl;
}

void fill (int * x) {
    x[1] = 3;
}
```

This code produces an out-of-bound situation, where the stack-value `b[0]` is overwritten by `fill(a)`.

The code has been compiled using

```
g++ main.cpp -fsanitize=undefined -lstdc++ -lubsan
```

however the sanitizer is unable to detect the error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: [Works for me](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b60daeaa0736f6dd).

Comment: @PaulR seems like this is caused by your additional -O2 flag.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Not too surprising I suppose, as the compiler does a lot more analysis when optimisation is enabled, and some other features don't work when optimisation is disabled (e.g. detecting use of uninitiailised variables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes. Stack overflows are detected by the address santizer, not the UB santizer. Compiling your snippet with `-fsanitize=address` gives

> ```
> =17847==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address ... at pc ...
>
> #0 0x10f7f5d44 in fill(int*) (a.out:x86_64+0x100000d44)
> #1 0x10f7f5b81 in main (a.out:x86_64+0x100000b81)
> #2 0x7fff5f490014 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1014)
>
> ...
> ```

Technically, an out of bounds access on the stack does lead to undefined behavior. But putting everything that leads to UB into the UB sanitizer is probably too little separation of concerns. From the [clang address sanitizer docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html):

> AddressSanitizer is a fast memory error detector. It consists of a compiler instrumentation module and a run-time library. The tool can detect the following types of bugs:
>
> - Out-of-bounds accesses to heap, stack and globals
> - ...

while the list of checks that the UB sanitizer implements can be found [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#available-checks) (again, clang docs).

Comment: `-fsanitize=undefined` does seem to work for this example though, at least with gcc - see link in comments above.

Comment: @PaulR I saw the link, that's interesting. I wasn't aware of notable differences between clang and gcc sanitizer implementations.

Comment: Me neither - I tend to use clang mainly these days but noticed this when I tried unsuccessfully to reproduce his problem with gcc.